# Mysql, all the data is deleted as i closed my workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So I am having this problem where I enter data in MySQL table everything works fine it stored in the table and when I read it with the select command it perfectly works but when I close my workbench my all the entries are removed only the null table is there

Comment: Could you be forgetting to do a COMMIT

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most common mistake would be that you are not committing the data. Workbeanch opens a connection that isolates you from the rest of the DB and all your changes are visible only to yourself. When you close the Client (without committing) you end up making a `ROLLBACK`.

Call `COMMIT;` [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) or click the respective button in the client.

If you do not want to write the command you can use the appropriate buttons:

[image: Workbench COMMIT Button]

[Find out more here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-commit-changes-in-MySql-workbench)

Comment: This is a big assumption for an answer. This is not the default state I have ever come across with MySQL

Comment: This is a very nice guess, but a guess just the same. We do not know if the OP uses innodb in the first place. Even if the OP uses innodb, by default autocommit is enabled meaning modifications are committed without an explicit commit, unless a multi-statemen transaction is initiated. And in case of a rollback, no null values remain.

Comment: is there any way without writing commit?

Comment: Does with commit work?

Comment: @AbdullahRehmani https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-commit-changes-in-MySql-workbench

Comment: Yes with commit it works.

Comment: @Shadow - indeed a long shot, but also the most obvious. Maybe the -1 is not deserved after all ;)